# Laravel pivottable Validate uniquenes for a new user with personalnumber and company in company_user table

Tags: php, laravel, validation, unique

I have a system where a user can be added, the user itself has a personalnumber in a company.
So I created a pivvottable  company_users with id, company_id and user_id to store the "belongsToMany" relationships.
In my form creating a new user I have to validate that a user defined for a company don't have the same personalnumber as another user in the same company.
So validation is not as simple as using unique on the company_users pivottable.

I am sending in my $request->

- personalnumber (entered by a person in that form) and
- company_id also selected by a person filling the form.

So I need to verify that this new user can be added to the db with his own unique personalnumber and the specific company.

in my store method:

```
  ` public function store(Request $request)
     {
     //dd($request);
         $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
           //'personalnummer' => ['personalnummer' => new PersonalnummerFirma],
            'personalnummer' => [],
`
```

I tried to figure how to check but I didn't find a solution :(

in my companycontroller I have:

```
  public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

in my users controller I have:

```
 public function firmas() {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Firma');


}
```

because some Bosses or employees can be part of different companies whith their own specific personalnumber per company.

In normal php-style I would get all users from db and save them into an array and then run through the array while checking if user.personalnumber + given $request->company.id exist in the pivottable
company_users -> if yes the validation fails.
How can I achieve that in Laravel validation I can't write there in my store method:
'personalnummer' => [$users= USER:all(); foreach $users as $user
...
I've found many examples here with 2 inputfields which had to be unique but ... none with a third "variable" which is my not yet existing user.

Thanks to all out there!!

Answer (score 1):

I assume by saying

> in my companycontroller I have:

and

> in my users controller I have:

you meant that you have that code in your **Company** and **User** model files.
I assume that you have defined your relations correctly.

Then, based on what you have said i would do something like that:
(https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#using-closures) - if you need to this kind of validator only once in your application,

```php
Validator::make($request->all(), [
  'personal_number' => [
    function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($request) {
      $company = Company::findOrFail($request->input('company_id'));

      if (!$company->users()->get('personal_number')->contains('personal_number', $value)) {
        $fail("Person with personal number {$value} is already registered in company with id {$company->id}");
      }
    }
  ]
]);
```

If that's not what you meant, let me know.

Comment: Exactly what I need!  But I don't have access to the $request variable in the function, so $request->input('company_id') doens't work :(, I tried to send instead of $attribute the $request object but isn't working also ... :( I am still trying to figure out to pass the $request object into the function. If you have an idea for me would be great - still searching :) -> Error in Laravel: ErrorException
Undefined variable: request

Comment: You can access request data by using request() helper

Comment: Oh! I forgot to add "use" clause. Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much it is working as expected!
I changed in my code the "if not" to "if" statement and get(['personal_number']) << Laravel told me it needs to be an array. now it works!
Thank you very much Magiczne for your fast and reliable help!